# React : How can I edit the form?

Tags: reactjs

I am using localStorage to store the form details. When the component is mounted I am getting the data in the console. How can I show the data in the form and edit it? I've set the edited state but I am not getting how can I achieve this so that the values will be prefilled?

### Here's the code :

```
class MileStoneForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
                deliverable_name:"",
                due_date:"",
                deliverable_notes:"",
                milestone_based_payment:false,
                deliverable_name_error:"",
                due_date_error:"",
                deliverable_notes_error:"",
                percent_rate:0,
                percent_rate_error:"",
                due_date_select:false,
                edit:false,
                milestonedata:null;
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        let milestonedata=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mileStoneData'))
        console.log(milestonedata)
        if(this.state.edit===true){
            this.setState({
                milestonedata:milestonedata
            },()=>{this.setEditMileStoneData()})
        }
    }

    setEditMileStoneData=()=>{
        const {milestonedata}=this.state
        let data={
            deliverable_name:milestonedata.milestoneName,
            deliverable_notes:milestonedata.description,
            due_date:milestonedata.dueDate,
            milestone_based_payment:milestonedata.isMilestoneBasedPayment,
            percent_rate:milestonedata.percentageRate
        }
        this.setState({...data})
    }

handleSubmit=()=>{
        const {deliverable_name,deliverable_name_error,deliverable_notes,deliverable_notes_error,
            due_date,due_date_error,milestone_based_payment,percent_rate}=this.state
        let pass=true
        if(pass){
            let data={
                    description: deliverable_notes,
                    dueDate: due_date,
                    isDeleted: false,
                    isMilestoneBasedPayment: milestone_based_payment,
                    milestoneName: deliverable_name,
                    percentageRate: percent_rate,
            }
            console.log(data)
            this.props.handleData(data)  
            localStorage.setItem('mileStoneData',JSON.stringify(data))
            this.setState({
                deliverable_name:'',
                deliverable_name_error:'',
                deliverable_notes:'',
                deliverable_notes_error:'',
                milestone_based_payment:false,
                percent_rate:'',
                due_date:'',
                due_date_error:''
            })   
        }
    } 
   export default MileStoneForm
```

Comment: Can you post your render function, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the ["controlled components"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) section from React docs.

The thought behind it is:

1. You create a state object for your form.
2. You add the state for each form field as its value
3. You add a function to `onChange` that updates the satate.

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controlled component is the way to go here. I usually like to do it this way.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   // This way when we a change is made within the field this function is called and the name from the input will be changed with the new value provided
   this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value })
}


render(){
   <TextInput value = { this.state.NAME_THIS_CORRELATING_TO_THE_KEY_IN_STATE } name = "NAME_THIS_CORRELATING_TO_THE_KEY_IN_STATE" onChange = { this.handleChange }
}
```

We then do this for all of our components